# Hibernate + oracle sequence + trigger

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, persistence, sequence

I have a table with an index auto filled by a trigger that use a sequence (Oracle database)

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  IDS                           NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL
)


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER A_TRG
BEFORE INSERT
ON A REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.IDS := A_SEQ.nextval;
END A_TRG;
/
```

I have a matching Java class:

```
Class A {
   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "aSequence", sequenceName = "A_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "aSequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   @Column(name = "IDS")
   Long id;

   ...
}
```

When I try to persist an instance of A like this:

```
EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
A a = new A();
Long id = getHibernateTemplate().save(a);
transaction.commit();
```

I get this problem:

- ID in code returned by the save call = **"X"**
- ID in database = **"X+1"**

Is there a way to setup Hibernate to let the database trigger create the ID ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reponse found at [HIbernate issue with Oracle Trigger for generating id from a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002119/hibernate-issue-with-oracle-trigger-for-generating-id-from-a-sequence)

I need to adapt my trigger to run only if no ID is given:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER A_TRG
BEFORE INSERT
ON A REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (New.IDS is null) -- (1)
BEGIN
  :new.IDS := A_SEQ.nextval;
END A_TRG;
/
```

(1) this line allow Hibernate to manually call A_SEQ.nextVal to set the ID and then bypass the trigger else Hibernate will get the nextval for uselessly because the trigger will always reset the ID calling nextval again

Answer (score 1):

In your class B you have `@GeneratedValue(generator = "preferenceSequence")` which not defined in the example that you have, it should be  `@GeneratedValue(generator = "bSequence")`

By default hibernate allocation size is 50 the B: IDS=50 seems to suggest the mapping is picking the wrong sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just changed preferenceSequence -> bSequence (copy-paste error). Allocation size is forced to 1, A's ID and B's ID are not linked, given values are not real ones, it's just to give an example. The important values are A.IDS and B.A_IDS that are not equals :-/
Regards

Comment: is your problem solved? if so please mark my response as the answer

Comment: My problem is not solved, the persist call generate a "B" instance with a bad "A" ID. As said in the example I found that A.ids=10 but B.a.ids=9.