# Hibernate/JPA - use trigger for String PK

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this Entity with a Pk String:

```
@Table(name = "EX_ENTITY")
public class ExEntity implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
```

For this Oracle table, there is a trigger associated to the pk:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TR_SEQ_ID
 BEFORE INSERT ON SCHEMA.EX_ENTITY
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.ID is null)
DECLARE
  
  v_id VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN 
 
 SELECT ID.NEXTVAL
  INTO v_id
 FROM DUAL;
 
 SELECT LPAD(TO_CHAR(v_id),15,'0') 
   INTO id_15
 FROM DUAL;
 
 :NEW.ID := id_15; 
 
 END;
```

How are the annotations and the correct code for associate trigger to the key?

Thanks for the response

Comment: You might want to make use of sequence generator for incrementing the primary key, please refer to the following link https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-strategies-when-set-primary-key

Comment: Also this post gives an idea about editing your trigger to go along with the sequence
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418163/hibernate-oracle-sequence-trigger