# ORA-00917: missing comma error while using custom oracle sequence in hiberanate

Tags: hibernate

Hi i am getting this error while i am trying to use my oracle db sequence in hibernates.
i am using this declaration :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_DETAILS")
public class User {


@GenericGenerator(name = "generator",strategy = "sequence-identity",parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence",value = "USER_ID_SEQ")} )
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int userid;

..
```

and using this to persist my entity instance:

```
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        //creating the new transaction from the above created session that is starting a new unit of work
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(user);
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("User saved successfully in the database");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
```

but i am getting the error:

```
Apr 11, 2013 11:10:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00917: missing comma

caught : ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Could anyone assist on this?

Comment: Please set the sql trace with `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` and post the output. There you (and we) can see which comma Oracle doesn't like.

Comment: Here it is :Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        T_USER_DETAILS2
        (USER_ID, USER_ADDRESS, USER_AGE, USER_EMAIL, USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_LASTNAME, USER_PASSWORD, USER_PHONE) 
    values
        (next value for my_sequence, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 16, 2013 1:19:37 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 917, SQLState: 42000
Apr 16, 2013 1:19:37 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00917: missing comma

caught : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: i have just my table name and sequence name everything else is still same and i am stil gettign the same error

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle the correct syntax is `USER_ID_SEQ.nextval` so that's probably where your syntax error is coming from.

Here's an example thread with some code you can refer to: [HIbernate issue with Oracle Trigger for generating id from a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002119/hibernate-issue-with-oracle-trigger-for-generating-id-from-a-sequence)

[Edit]
From the link try using ...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="a1")
@SequenceGenerator(name="a1", sequenceName="USER_ID_SEQ")
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int userid;
```

... and upgrade to the latest Hibernate JAR

Comment: yes i know that...problem here is i am not writing this query its the hibernate which is generating it for me when i calls save(user) method. thoughts???

Comment: From the link I posted. I'd recommend using the same annotations as they have described i.e. `GeneratedValue` and `SequenceGenerator` to see if that changes the behaviour. Also upgrade your version of Hibernate in case this is an issue that has been subsequently fixed.