# How to persist an entity will null primary key

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink JPA implementation. I need to persist an entity with null primary key. The key are generated by a trigger and therefore must always be null for new rows. Nothing can be changed in the database, so none of the @GeneratedValue options is suitable.

I tried @PrimaryKey(validation=IdValidation.NONE), but it does not help.
I always receive an error like:
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in UnitOfWork clone

Currently I am using a simple insert statement.

Could anyone suggest what to change to be able to use persist() method with new entities with null pk?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108229/how-do-i-annotate-id-column-if-value-is-generated-by-a-trigger

Comment: If you can make this work then it will almost certainly involve the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.  You denied that any of the available strategies are suitable, but have you tried `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)`?  Even though your PK column is not actually an identity / auto-increment column, it behaves like one in many ways.

Comment: If the `IDENTITY` strategy cannot be made to work for you, then I don't think JPA offers a solution.  You may, however, find a feature specific to EclipseLink (can't help with that) or specific to another JPA-compatible persistence provider, such as Hibernate.

Comment: Identity produces the same error "Null or zero primary key encountered in UnitOfWork clone"  because there is no identity, i am using Oracle db. But thanks for the indication on Hibernate

Comment: I'd bet that the reason `IDENTITY` gives that result is not directly that the column is not an identity column, but that the DB driver does not recognize the trigger-created keys as generated keys (c.f. [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys())).  The distinction may not matter a bit, but if there were a way to make Oracle recognize your trigger as a key generator then that would likely solve the problem.

Comment: You need to use IDENTITY to have EclipseLink/JPA read back in the primary key that is set by the database.  The exception you are getting is unrelated, likely because you haven't configured it fully, forcing entities to be cached against a null pk.  What database are you using?  If it isn't one that can support returning set values, then you might need to use a stored procedure for the inserts as described here http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm