# saveAndFlush in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISC")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "discId" })
public class Disc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ReturnInsert
    @Column(name = "DISC_ID")
    private Long discId;
..
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface DiscRepository extends JpaRepository<Disc, Long> {
...
}
```

but when I save using saveAndFlush() I have this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108229/how-do-i-annotate-id-column-if-value-is-generated-by-a-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't set the `discId` field, as simple as that.
If you want to delegate this to the framework use `@GeneratedValue` (and set strategy which corresponds to your DB). The framework will handle the ids generation for you.

Comment: I set it throught a Trigger in the DB

Comment: Yes, but I guess Your JPA provider has no idea at flush time that there's a trigger generating the primary key. If possible, consider changing primary key generated by database sequence and then point the sequence name in @GeneratedValue(strategy=Generation Type. Sequence, generator = "my_generator") and then @SequenceGenerator(name="my_generator", sequenceName ="your_db_sequence_name"). Place those 2 annotations above your primary key field. You can try it out with your trigger name in the sequenceName. I haven't tried that. Maybe it will work with trigger too